Intel SIMD. Векторизация. Как рассчитывать сумму элементов массива uint8 переменной длины ? Размер массива может быть любым от 1 до 1000?
Если размер массива кратен 16 или 8 , то вопросов нет.
А если   не кратен , то не понятно , как загнать в __m128i   1, 2 или 5 uint8 из массива
( .т.е остаток) ?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Остаток считается без SIMD. Учтите также, что нужно проверять адрес начала массива на кратность, в соответствии с требованиями SIMD. Кстати, 1000 это очень маленький массив для векторизации.

С выравниванием адреса массива все понятно.  И все-же  как запихнуть 3 байта ИЛИ 15 из массива в __m128 ?  :)

Ничего не надо запихивать. Часть массива (начало, конец), которые не удовлетворяют требованиям SIMD, обрабатывайе в обычном цикле, без SIMD. Если применимо в вашем случае, можно создавать массив с запасными элементами, которые дополняют последний отрезок до полного.

Эх жаль нет __m128i  _mm_loadu_epu8( uchar * mem_adr , const int  imm8   ). Остается вариант копировать остаток в  uchar m[16] и его уже передать в блок команд SIMD. Спасибо Alex F  !
